# check if inequality is real

Tags: inequality, induction, fake-proofs

check if inequality is real:

30n < 2^n + 105

my solution proposal:

1. n=1 
   30<107 true
2. n=k    30k < 2^k +105

30(k+1) < 2^{k+1} + 105
Proof
30(k+1) < 2^{k+1} + 105

30k+30< 2^k +105+30=2^k +135

2^k +135 < 2*2^k+105

2^k + 135 < 2^k + 2^k +105

30 < 2^k

K> 5

n=5 
30(5+1)< 2^{5+1} +105
180< 2^6+105=169 
this is not true...

So, which conclusion follows from this ? 
what can you say about it?
I have no conclusions about this inequality ... Help

Answer (score 0):

I would write $$2^n>30n-105$$ then we have to prove that $$2^{n+1}>30(n+1)-105$$
Multiplying $$2^n>30n-105$$ by $2$ then
$$2^{n+1}>60n-210$$ Now you have to prove that $$60n-210>30(n+1)-105$$

Comment: I have: n>4,5 so n=5 .... But when I check it and substitute it to 2 ^ {n + 1}> 30 (n + 1) -105..receives 64> 75 thie is not true

Comment: I got $$30n>210+30-105$$ and now i need a calculator!

Comment: Do you got it now?

Comment: I solved the same and leaves n>4,5 but n belongs to natural numbers

Comment: inequality is real but the successor (n+1) does not

Comment: It gives $$n>\frac{9}{2}$$

Comment: As you have also written, the inequalitiy is real (or true)